# Confused by data binding and selecting specific data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and am confused by the notion of joining data to DOM elements.  I have a non-trivial data store in JSON of which I'm having difficulty segregating out different sections.
Here is my JSON:

```
var data ={ 
    "groups" :
    [{
        "name": "group1",
        "atts":
        [{
            "nodes": 
             [
             {"id": "root", "name": "Plaintext Router" },
             { "id": "B", "name": "Ethernet Switch" },
             { "id": "C", "name": "1.10" },
             { "id": "D", "name": "1.1" },
             { "id": "E", "name": "1.2" }
             ], 
            "links": 
             [{ "source": "root", "target": "B" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "C" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "D" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "E" },
             ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "group2",
        "atts":
        [{
            "nodes":
             [
             { "id": "root", "name": "Plaintext Router" },
             { "id": "B", "name": "Ethernet Switch" },
             { "id": "C", "name": "1.1" },
             { "id": "D", "name": "1.2" }
             ],
            "links":
             [{ "source": "root", "target": "B" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "C" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "D" },
             ]

        }]
    }
]
}
```

So, I have two groups that I want to create a network map for.  The root node is a the center with links emanating out in a spoke pattern to the other nodes surrounding the center.

I want to be able to choose which group to visualize.  I don't want them both visualized at the same time.

The code I have to try to do that is as follows.

```
var height = 600;
var width = 600;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(300))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(data.groups, key)
```

**[[need to get to links array of the selected group]]**

```
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke","green");

var groups = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.groups, key)
```

**[[Need to get to nodes array of selected group]]**

```
    .enter()
    .append("g");

var node = groups.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.w * 2; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.h * 2; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.icon + ")"; });

function key(d) {
    return ((d.groups.name === "group1") ? d.groups.atts : null);
}
```

The above key function indicates that I want to map the 'group1' group.  The problem I'm having is I don't know how to get to the "atts" array of "nodes" and "links" tied to the chosen group.  I want to be able to assign the nodes and links where needed.

The error I'm getting now is:
"Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference"
in the 'key' function.

I left other directives out such as svg:patterns and others to try to keep things simple.  I hope this example gets my point across.

I appreciate any help you can give on this.

Comment: i dont really know what you mean. could you make a js fiddle? You can use ... .selectAll(...).each(function(d){... here you have the data ...})

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cbfmgcr0/1/ here is a starting point...

Comment: Thank you Tobias.  I have updated it to try to make a working version.  It has an error so it doesn't display properly.

Comment: where do you get the selected group?

Comment: It's hard-coded for now.  The plan is to have the selection injected into the js script from an external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .filter((d) => {...} you can filter your data and make a condition which data should be set. I hope this is what you mean...

Filter Example:

```
const words = ["spray", "limit", "elite", "exuberant", "destruction", "present", "happy"];
let longWords = words.filter(word => word.length > 6)
```

JS

```
var data ={ 
    "groups" :
    [{
        "name": "group1",
        "atts":
        [{
            "nodes": 
             [
             {"id": "root", "name": "Plaintext Router" },
             { "id": "B", "name": "Ethernet Switch" },
             { "id": "C", "name": "1.10" },
             { "id": "D", "name": "1.1" },
             { "id": "E", "name": "1.2" }
             ], 
            "links": 
             [{ "source": "root", "target": "B" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "C" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "D" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "E" },
             ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "group2",
        "atts":
        [{
            "nodes":
             [
             { "id": "root", "name": "Plaintext Router" },
             { "id": "B", "name": "Ethernet Switch" },
             { "id": "C", "name": "1.1" },
             { "id": "D", "name": "1.2" }
             ],
            "links":
             [{ "source": "root", "target": "B" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "C" },
              { "source": "root", "target": "D" },
             ]

        }]
    }
]
}





var height = 600;
var width = 600;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(300))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(data.groups.filter((d)=>{
    console.log("link")
    console.log(d)
    }))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke","green");

var groups = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.groups.filter((d)=>{
    console.log("group")
    console.log(d)
    }))
    .enter()
    .append("g");

var node = groups.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.w * 2; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.h * 2; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.icon + ")"; });

function key(d) {
    return ((d.name === "group1") ? d.atts : null);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbfmgcr0/29/)